# ListView with TextBoxes in UpdatePanel does not return values after OnTextChanged

Tags: asp.net, ajax, listview, textbox, updatepanel

I have a **ListView** with **TextBoxes** in it. 
When I enter a value in the TextBox A I want a calculated value to show up in TextBox B. I am doing this in the CodeBehind.
This works well until I place the ListView in an **UpdatePanel**.

On the **OnTextChanged** I would like to do some calculations/database actions (In the example beneath I just multiply the inserted value by 2).
Since I do not want to do a complete **PostBack** everytime I enter a value, I inserted an UpdatePanel. Also because I want to stay on the same scroll position.

**The first time** I enter a value the OnTextChanged method does everything as it should, but **the second time** the UpdatePanel seems to remove all calculated values and only returns the first inserted value.

In Debug mode everything works well, also in IE8, but not in FireFox,Chrome or IE9.
I assume I am not using the UpdatePanel as I should be?

aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Testing.aspx.cs" Inherits="Sales_NewOrderPOS" ClientIDMode="AutoID"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblItemNo" Text='<%# Eval("ItemNo") %>'  runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblItemDecription" Text='<%# Eval("ItemDescription") %>'  runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPalletQuantity" runat="server" Width="30px" OnTextChanged="TextChangedPallet" AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnitQuantity" runat="server" Width="30px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr> 
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="SP_SelectItems" TypeName="ItemClass">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

</asp:Content>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void TextChangedPallet(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtPalletQuantity = (TextBox)sender;
    ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)txtPalletQuantity.NamingContainer;
    TextBox txtUnitQuantity = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtUnitQuantity");
    txtUnitQuantity.Text = ((Convert.ToDecimal(txtPalletQuantity.Text) * 2)).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Just a quick guess, try putting the ObjectDataSource1 inside the UpdatePanel

Comment: Tried it before, but it doesn't help.